# Cannot generate VMAP classes from xsd

Tags: java, xml, xsd, maven-jaxb2-plugin, iab

I started a [project](https://github.com/moaxcp/generate-vmap-example) on github using maven-jaxb2-plugin to generate VMAP classes from the [vmap xsd](https://github.com/InteractiveAdvertisingBureau/vmap/blob/master/xsd/vmap.xsd).

The problem I am running into appears to be an issue with the xsd itself.

```
[ERROR] Error while parsing schema(s).Location [ file:/projects/generate-vmap-example/src/main/resources/vmap.xsd{144,70}].
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'vast:VAST' to a(n) 'element declaration' component.
```

Everything seems to be setup correctly. vmap.xsd declares the vast namespace and imports the vast xsd.

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:vmap="http://www.iab.net/videosuite/vmap" xmlns:vast="http://www.iab.net/videosuite/vast" targetNamespace="http://www.iab.net/videosuite/vmap" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" version="1.0">
    <xs:import namespace="http://www.iab.net/videosuite/vast" schemaLocation="vast3_draft.xsd"/>
```

The VAST element is used here.

```
    <xs:complexType name="VASTAdData_type">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="vast:VAST" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
```

Should the vmap xsd be modified for this to work? Why can't it find the VAST element?

You can view the full project [here](https://github.com/moaxcp/generate-vmap-example).

Answer (score 0):

In the **vast3_draft.xsd** file, if you add these attributs to the root `xsd:schema` element:

- xmlns="http://www.iab.net/videosuite/vast"
- targetNamespace="http://www.iab.net/videosuite/vast"

So it becomes this:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" 
    attributeFormDefault="unqualified" xmlns="http://www.iab.net/videosuite/vast" targetNamespace="http://www.iab.net/videosuite/vast">
```

Then the **vmap.xsd** should properly parse when class generation occurs again.

The reason for this error is because in the **vmap.xsd** schema, it's importing **vast3_draft.xsd** using the `targetNamespace` value of `http://www.iab.net/videosuite/vast` and that namespace isn't anywhere in the **vast3_draft.xsd** schema. An `xs:import` element always requires a `targetNamespace` attribute, so the imported schema needs this as well.

I'm guessing because it has the word 'draft' in the file name, the schema itself might not be complete. If you get a new updated version of the schema you'll have to edit the schema file again if it still doesn't have the above attributes in the `xs:schema` element.

Comment: Thanks for the help I will try it out. The draft file is actually the official file for this version. The IAB people are just weird like that.

Comment: This actually causes a new error

`[ERROR] Error while parsing schema(s).Location [ file:/projects/generate-vmap-example/src/main/resources/vast3_draft.xsd{21,118}].
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'AdSystem_type' to a(n) 'type definition' component.` I know vast3_draft.xml works on its own to generate classes.

Comment: I also added the xmlns attribute and got `SAXParseException: A class/interface with the same name "com.github.moaxcp.vast.vmap.ExtensionsType" is already in use. Use a class customization to resolve this conflict.`

Comment: @JohnMercier Can you update the github project so I can see for myself the changes you made?

Comment: Yes it is updated